# Class 'App\Models\Registration' not found even though i have import it

Tags: laravel

Class 'App\Models\Registration' not found, i have import Registration class

i am trying to save student_id with it corresponding subjects array
When i dump dd($request->all()) i get the excepted results which is

```
"student_id" => "1"
"subjects" => array:2 [▼
 0 => "1"
 1 => "2"
]
```

but i get an exception when i trying saving into the database

this is my registration scheme

```
 Schema::create('registrations', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id')->index();
        $table->string('subjects');

        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');

        $table->timestamps();;
    });
```

this is my registration model

```
   class Registration extends Model
   {
    protected $table = 'registrations';

    protected $fillable = ['student_id','subjects'];

    protected $cast = [
        'student_id'    => 'Integer',
        'subjects'      => 'array',
    ];

  public function student(){
    $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
  }

  public function subjects()
  {
    $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
  }

}
```

i am using checkbox array to get the subjects

```
 <input class="form-check-input" name="subjects[]" value="{{$subject->id}}" type="checkbox">
```

this is registration controller code, i have imported registration model

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Models\Registration;
  use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

  class RegistrationController extends BaseController
  {
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $registration = Registration::create(request()->validate([
        'student_id' => 'required|integer',
        'subjects' => 'required',
        'subjects.*'=> 'accepted',
    ]));

 }
```

i want to save the student_id with the subjects array

student    subjects

1         [2,4,5]`enter code here`

Comment: Is the registration model class file in App\Models namespace?  Since this question regards import/namespace issues it makes sense to show them.

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a `Models` folder inside of `App` by default (at least in earlier versions; not sure about new ones). But yeah, make sure your namespace matches your folder `namespace App\Models;` and make sure it's imported as `use App\Models\Registration;`

Comment: i have added the namespace that i used as can be seen @TimLewis

Comment: Not quite no; you've added the `use` statement of your controller, but I still don't see your `Registration` model's namespace. Paste the first couple lines of `App\Models\Registration.php`, specifically the `namespace`.

Comment: @TimLewis i don't get your point, do you mean like this    'namespace  App\Models'

Comment: Yes. In the code you've posted, you don't show your `namespace`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDHmQ.png. There's likely a few lines above your `class` declaration that you aren't showing.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis, i added the namespace to the Registration  model and the error is not displaying any more, but the data is not saving in the database

Comment: Nice! Yeah, namespace has to match folder structure. As for saving, you're likely getting an error, either validation is failing, or you're unable to save the `subjects` (it's gonna try to save the array value to a `subjects` column with the code you have now, but that approach won't work). Don't have time to answer today, but try a different approach; `$registration = Registration::create(...);`, followed by whatever logic you need to set subjects based on ids passed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a namespace.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Registration extends Model { ... }

?>
```

Also your model must be stored inside the directory **App/Models/*Registration.php***.

Answer (score 0):

i think you create your Registration model in App directory...please check your directory.then use

```
use App\Registration;
```

If It on App\Models directory then In Registration Model,

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
class Registration extends Model { }
```

Comment: the Registration model  is in App\Models directory

Comment: In Registration Model Then add a namespace App\Model like this   <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Registration extends Model
{
}